# Identify HTML tag at start of string and remove it

Tags: php, regex

I want to get html tag in string at starting position and remove it from the string

my demo strings are below:

```
<I>little willingness</I> that, as the Course itself was to emphasise
```

this will return  `<I>` tag as o/p

```
<p>little willingness</p> that, as the Course itself was to emphasise
```

this will return  `<p>` tag as o/p

```
little willingness that, <p>as the Course itself was to emphasise</p>
```

this will return me null as o/p

How do I modify my code below to check only for HTML tags at the start of the line and then remove them?

```
preg_match("/<[^<]+>/",$string,$m);
```

Comment: Please check your question once you write.

Comment: You reverted my edits and it says **this will return tag as o/p**. Does it make any sense? Seriously???

Comment: You probably ought to use `[^>]` in your regular expression, rather than `[^<]`.

Comment: Ok check again I revised my Question

Comment: I wanted to shorten your example, since the horizontal scrolling was unnecessary trouble.

Comment: Doing this will leave the closing tag for the pair still open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Step:

```
$paragraph = "<p><i>Please don't</i> blow me to pieces. How to put span here.</p>";
$sentences = explode(".", $paragraph);
```

Next, add `span` tags to each sentence:

```
foreach($sentences as &$sentence) {
    $sentence = "<span>$sentence</span>";
}
```

Finally, re-implode them into a paragraph:

```
$paragraph = implode(".", $sentences);
```

Answer (score 1):

Code

```
<?php
$str = "<I>little willingness</I> that, <b>as</b> the Course itself was to emphasise again and again.";
if(preg_match('/^(<.*?>)/', $str, $matches))
{
    $str = preg_replace('/^(<.*?>)/', '', $str);
}

print $str;
var_dump($matches);
```

prints:

```
little willingness</I> that, <b>as</b> the Course itself was to emphasise again and again.
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "<I>"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "<I>"
}
```

So, you get the string without the tag at the beginning and the tag value in $matches.